# remove item from minicart in magento 1.9x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento-1.9

i want to remove item from minicart but using custom jquery ui popup. here is the default code 
template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml

```
 <?php if (!$this->isOnCheckoutPage()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAjaxDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>"
           data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>"
           class="remove">
            <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This works fine.but i want custom popup instead of default alert. so i used jquery popup.

```
<div id="dialog123" title="Confirmation Required">
            Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAjaxDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>" class="remove-this-item">
           <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var $x=jQuery.noConflict();
            $x(document).ready(function() {
            $x("#dialog123").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true
                });
            });

        $x(".remove-this-item").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $x(this).attr("href");

            $x("#dialog123").dialog({
            buttons : {
            "Confirm" : function() {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
            },
            "Cancel" : function() {
            $x(this).dialog("close");
            }
            }
        });

        $x("#dialog123").dialog("open");
        });
        </script>
```

using this popup only, i have to perform ajax delete operation. above code redirects to next page when confirmed YES.